# How to communicate pid from one PHP process to another?

Tags: php, linux, posix

There is a long-lived PHP process, which supports signals (`SIGHUP` etc.) and another PHP process needs to know the PID of the first one to send a signal.

I'd like to set an environment variable, which would be read in the second (client) process and used for my purposes, but `putenv(...posix_getpid()...)` doesn't seem to make it visible to another process.

How do I make an environment variable, set in one PHP process, visible to another? If that's impossible, what's the preferred way (I'd like not to use files or db for this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is [Inter-Process Communication (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Solutions include using a socket, a named pipe, a file, redis, some message bus/queue, etc. This is a common and complex problem in software development, and one with many many robust options.

Sounds like a simple file would work fine for you and is probably the... simplest.

Answer (score 3):

A common practice is to create a globally-known `pid` file when starting the daemon process, and writing its PID to that file.

Other processes willing to send signals to the daemon just read the pid file to retrieve its current pid and send the signal thereafter.